# Issue with Activity Context and SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting a nullPointerException in my code when i try pull all the columns out of my (small) database.  From what I can tell, it's caused by me not having the right Activity context when creating my database.  It's great knowing what i'm doing wrong, but i can't see how to fix it!  can any of you point me in the right direction?

Here is my method for pulling the data out.

```
    public ArrayList<Task> getAllTasks() throws ParseException {
    ArrayList<Task>  tempArraList = null;
    Task tempTask = null;

    String[] cols = {TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_ID,
            TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_DESCRIPTION,
            TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_DATETIME,
            TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_CATEGORY
    };
    String selection = "*";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String groupBy = null;
    String having = null;
    String orderBy = null;



    Cursor c = database.query(
            TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            cols,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            groupBy,
            having,
            orderBy
    );
    int index = 1;
    while (c.moveToNext()){

        if (index == 0){ tempTask.location = c.getInt(c.getPosition());}
        if (index == 1){ tempTask.task = c.getString(c.getPosition());}
        if (index == 2){ tempTask.date.setTime(sdf.parse(c.getString(c.getPosition())));}
        if (index == 3){
            tempTask.category = c.getString(c.getPosition());
            tempArraList.add(tempTask);
        }

        index ++;
        if (index == 4){index = 0;};

    }
    c.close();

    return tempArraList;
}
```

Here is the header on my Database class

```
public class TaskDatabase {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Taskdb";
private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
private static final String TAG = "DatabaseConnector";
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private taskDBHelper dbOpenHelper;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d kk:mm", Locale.getDefault());

public TaskDatabase(Context context) {
    dbOpenHelper = new taskDBHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME);
}

public void openDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException
{
    //open database in reading/writing mode
    database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void closeDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException
{
    if (database != null)
        database.close();
}
```

and Here is my Helper class.

```
public class taskDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d kk:mm", Locale.getDefault());
private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                TaskDBContract.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_DESCRIPTION + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_DATETIME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_CATEGORY + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + " )";

private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME;
// If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.


public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


public taskDBHelper(Context context, String name) {
    super(context, name, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public taskDBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
    super(context, name, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
    // to simply to discard the data and start over
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}

public String insertTask(Task temptask) {
    sdf.setCalendar(temptask.date);


    String SQL_TASK_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " + TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME +
            "(" + TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_DESCRIPTION + COMMA_SEP +
            TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_DATETIME + COMMA_SEP +
            TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_CATEGORY + COMMA_SEP + " ) VALUES (" +
            temptask.task + COMMA_SEP + sdf.format(temptask.date) + COMMA_SEP +
            temptask.category + ")";

    return SQL_TASK_INSERT;
}

public void InsertTaskArray(ArrayList<Task> taskArrayList) {


    for (int j = 0; j < taskArrayList.size(); j++) {
        sdf.setCalendar(taskArrayList.get(j).date);

        String SQL_TASK_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " + TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                "(" + TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_DESCRIPTION + COMMA_SEP +
                TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_DATETIME + COMMA_SEP +
                TaskDBContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_CATEGORY + COMMA_SEP + " ) VALUES (" +
                taskArrayList.get(j).task + COMMA_SEP + sdf.format(taskArrayList.get(j).date) + COMMA_SEP +
                taskArrayList.get(j).category + ")";
    }

}
```

}

and the crash log (added)

```
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.balefire.test, PID: 9032
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.balefire.test/com.example.balefire.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.balefire.test.TaskDatabase.getAllTasks(TaskDatabase.java:138)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.balefire.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-01 01:51:29.144 9032-9032/com.example.balefire.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I know i'm doing something stupid and just can't see it!!

Comment: show crash log and where you are using `TaskDatabase` class

Comment: Crash log has been added

Comment: show TaskDatabase class full code

Comment: @Deviousterran where is your  `getAllTasks()` method defined? Inside some Activity class?

Comment: @ Droidwala getAllTasks() is defined in the TaskDatabase class along with all my database insert and extract queries.  The main activity calls getAllTasks() (and other queries, none of which work) when the user clicks a button which is SUPPOSE to return a a arraylist of my custom 'Task' object  but throws a null pointer exception when the query is called.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your database object inside  `getAllTasks()` method like below:

```
SQLiteDatabase database;
taskDbHelper dbhelper;
dbhelper = new taskDbHelper(<Activity_Name>.this,TaskDatabase.DATABASE_NAME);
database = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

Then you could call your `database.query()` method.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: @Deviousterran did that worked well?